# Unwanted space before Japanese bracket '「' in luatexja

Tags: spacing, brackets, luatexja

I'm compiling a document with `lualatex` and `luatexja`.
If `\item` is followed by bracket symbol `「`, then an unwant space is introduced.

[image: Example pdf]

Demo code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  「」

  「」

\item
  日本語

  日本語

\item
  english

  english
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Version:
`This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)`   `\ProvidesPackage{luatexja-core}[2016/05/15 Core of LuaTeX-ja]`
I also tried the version on git [LuaTeX-ja OSDN](https://zh.osdn.net/projects/luatex-ja/scm/git/luatexja/).

Comment: Reported [here](https://osdn.net/ticket/browse.php?group_id=5593&tid=37100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there is a glue by `\item` before `「`. Since “character class of a glue” is zero in the standard metric, a half-width space is inserted between a glue and `「`.

To solve this issue, we can patch `\@item`, as in `ltjsarticle.cls`.

```
\def\@item[#1]{%
  (...)
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi
    \directlua{luatexja.jfmglue.create_beginpar_node()}% <-- !!! add !!!
  }%
  (...)
}
```

Or, do the same thing using `\apptocmd`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@item}{\everypar{}\fi}
  {\everypar{}\fi\directlua{luatexja.jfmglue.create_beginpar_node()}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem is resolved with your patch or using document class `ltjsarticle`.  But both methods fail when package `luatexja-ruby` is used.